# Create a string columns based on values of columns and index Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    A   B
Tenor       
1   15.1726 0.138628
2   15.1726 0.147002
3   15.1726 0.155376
4   15.1726 0.163749
5   15.1726 0.172123
```

I want to be able to create another column that has a string by concatenating the previous columns, including the index. For instance, first row of this new columns would be: `XXXX1XXXX15.1726XXXX0.138628`

How can I do that in Pandas? If I try to use `df[ColumnName]` in the string formula Pandas will always bring the index, which will mess up my string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this was interesting

```
df.reset_index().applymap('XXXX{}'.format).sum(1)

0    XXXX1XXXX15.1726XXXX0.138628
1    XXXX2XXXX15.1726XXXX0.147002
2    XXXX3XXXX15.1726XXXX0.155376
3    XXXX4XXXX15.1726XXXX0.163749
4    XXXX5XXXX15.1726XXXX0.172123
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use apply

```
df['NewCol'] = df.apply(lambda x: "XXXX" + str(x.name) + "XXXX" + str(x.A) + "XXXX" + str(x.B), axis=1)
```

also, a bit shorter, from @Abdou

```
df['joined'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'XXXX'+'XXXX'.join(map(str,x)),axis=1)
```

Comment: `df['joined'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'XXX'+'XXX'.join(map(str,x)),axis=1)` should be shorter.

Comment: Steven, I could not replicate what you showed. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
df['newColumn'] = [("XXXX"+str(id)+"XXXX" +str(entry.A) + "XXXX" +str(entry.B)) for id,entry in df.iterrows()]
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I wanted